# Reducing application size after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, compilation, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I had a customtkinter app that need to be compile. After that compile, I can see some unused module had being compile together, making the app much bigger. Is there any way to reduce the size by automatically detect and removing unused module? I believe in the javascript, the bundler automatically detect and do 'treeshaking'. So, is there any official/trusted treeshaker in python?

Reducing python app size after compiling with pyinstaller